# how to pass data from login page to another url in flutter?

Tags: javascript, flutter, web

i want to pass login data (ID) from login page to another url (not other class in the same project) in flutter

example :
i want to open "http://mylink.com/test"(example url) but i also want to pass ID from "http://mylink.com/login"(example url)

i tried to use :

```
final _dataID = {"loginid" : "$id"};
final url = Uri.encodeFull('http://mylink.com/test/$_dataID');
html.open.window(url,"test");
```

but it's not working, how to achieve that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Kevin Malix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13811228/kevin-malix) it depends on how your endpoint is getting this ID value:

Try this:

```
//final _dataID = {"loginid" : "$id"};
final url = Uri.encodeFull('http://mylink.com/test?loginid=$id');
html.open.window(url,"test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```flutter
import 'dart:js' as js;

.
.
.
 js.context.callMethod("open", ["http://mylink.com/test/$_dataID"]);
```